# An alternative proof of the primitive element theorem using linear equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I want to prove the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) for finite Galois extensions of $\mathbb Q$ along the following lines. Suppose $E/\mathbb Q$ is a finite Galois extension with basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. By the [Steinitz exchange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) we can assume $x_1 = 1 \in \mathbb Q$. Set $\alpha = 1 + x_2 + \ldots x_n$ and consider the equation
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^m c_k \alpha^k = 0.
$$
If we substitute the sum for $\alpha$, multiply out, write cross products of the $x_i$'s in terms of sums of the $x_i$, and rearrange we find an equation in the $x_i$ where the coefficients came from this rearrangement. Hence we have $n$ equalities (the terms before the $x_i$) and $m$ indeterminates (the $c_k$'s). So for $m = n$ we can solve for the $c_k$ non-trivially. This gives us a polynomial $f = c_n X^n + \ldots + c_1 X + c_0$ with $f(\alpha) = 0$, to show that its root generates $E$ over $\mathbb Q$ we have to show that $c_n \ne 0$ and $c_n^{-1} \cdot f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, but here I do not know how to proceed?

> So is it possible to show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $n$, or to alter the above proof so as to give this result?

Comment: Your "equation" isn't an equation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for pointing out. I just forgot to equate it to zero!

Comment: The minimal polynomial of this particular $\alpha$ (or of any particular element) may not have degree $n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So, it is even not possible to write any algebraic expression of the $x_i$ for $\alpha$ so that some has a minimal polynomial of degree $n$? So if this particular one does not works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element $\alpha$ is not necessarily primitive. The first counterexample that occured to me is with $E=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Let
$$
\mathcal{B}=\{x_1=1,x_2=\sqrt2+\sqrt6,x_3=\sqrt3, x_4=-\sqrt2-\sqrt3\}.
$$
The coordinates of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ with respect to the "natural" basis $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6\}$ form the matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\cr0&1&0&-1\cr0&0&1&-1\cr0&1&0&0\cr}.
$$
We easily see that $\det A=1$, so $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis. But
$$
\alpha=1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1+\sqrt6
$$
is clearly not primitive.

---

If there are any intermediate fields $K$ between $E$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ it should be possible to select the basis in such a way that $\alpha\in K$. The trick of including $1$ in the basis only serves to prove that $\alpha\notin\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So you have selected $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6)$ so that $\alpha \in K$. But would be interesting if there is any other expression for $\alpha$ instead of the sum possible so that the above will work...

Comment: Nothing simple comes to mind @StefanH. If we have a Galois extension it suffices to find an element not fixed by any non-trivial element of the Galois group, but then the choice of basis needs to depend on the Galois group. There are *normal bases* (=bases consisting of Galois conjugates).  But constructing them starting from an arbitrary basis is... I don't see a recipe. Anyway, a random element of $E$ is primitive "with probability $1$" (not specifying a distribution here!). The exceptions form a finite union of proper subspaces.

Comment: An element not fixed by any non-trivial element of the Galois group does not lie in a proper normal extension, but it might nonetheless lie in some (necessary not normal) extension $\mathbb Q \subset K \subsetneq E$  ($K/\mathbb Q$ not normal), or not?